# Error in react-native-imagepicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'

import Screen from './app/components/Screen';

export default function App() {

  const requestPermission = async () => {
    const { granted } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
    if (!granted)
      alert('Enable permission');
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    requestPermission();
  }, [])

  return (
    <Screen></Screen>
  );
}
```

I tried to use "expo-image-picker" to grant camera roll permission from the user.But when I run my project it says "ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync() is deprecated in favour of ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()" . Also, no alert box shows on my android device . Can anyone explain the situation?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the

```
ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync()
```

has become obsolete, so you should use

```
ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()
```